# How do you get the last say 20 "Close price" values from python-binance using the "Get Historical Kline/Candlesticks" function?

Tags: python, trading, cryptocurrency, binance, candlesticks

I am trying to make a list from the last few "close price" values on binance.
This is the code that I currently have.

```
from binance.client import Client
client= Client(API_KEY,API_SECRET)
klines = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", 
Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, "1 day ago UTC")
print(klines)
```

The output is multiple lists described as follows:

```
[
  [
    1499040000000,      // Open time
    "0.01634790",       // Open
    "0.80000000",       // High
    "0.01575800",       // Low
    "0.01577100",       // Close
    "148976.11427815",  // Volume
    1499644799999,      // Close time
    "2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
    308,                // Number of trades
    "1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
    "28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
    "17928899.62484339" // Ignore.
  ]
]
```

Here is an example of the output with the middle removed:

```
[[1611072420000, '37716.64000000', '37805.00000000', '37702.18000000', 
'37787.54000000', '198.73546400', 1611072479999, '7507515.26251034', 3959, 
'139.54353300', '5272053.83992940', '0'], [1611072480000, '37787.54000000', 
'37805.00000000', '37654.11000000', '37756.09000000', '123.42784000', 
1611072539999, '4658049.45239573', 3060, '56.22527600', '2122388.53330171', 
'0'], [1611072540000, '37754.74000000', '37768.11000000', '37671.15000000', 
'37691.71000000', '137.19280300', 1611072599999, '5175284.11293547', 2775, 
'59.11196400', '2230236.36825285', '0'],.......................................................................... 
... [1611158700000, '33757.21000000', '33758.90000000', '33408.06000000', 
'33511.26000000', '455.99996000', 1611158759999, '15289773.46630533', 7233, 
'145.59824900', '4882553.68773912', '0'], [1611158760000, '33511.27000000', 
'33527.38000000', '33400.00000000', '33471.00000000', '308.54631700', 
1611158819999, '10323394.45427450', 4736, '157.52705800', 
'5271808.11720111', '0']]
```

I want to make a list consisting of the 5th [4] value of the last say 20 lists.

Not sure if there is a better function to use in python.

Comment: `all5th = [el[4] for el in a]` will get you all the 5th elements, and 
`last20of5th = all5th[-20:]` will get you the last 20 elements

Answer (score 0):

you can access to each items and properties by using : klines[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

"open   = [float(entry[1]) for entry in k_lines]"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).